# Optimize this slow mysql query

Tags: mysql, left-join, query-optimization, inner-join

```
SELECT SUM( a.situacao =2 OR a.situacao =0 ) AS cotacoes, 
       SUM( a.situacao =1 ) AS n_publicar, 
       SUM( a.inicio <= NOW( ) AND DATE_ADD( a.inicio, INTERVAL a.duracao HOUR ) >= NOW( ) AND a.situacao =2 ) AS disputa, 
       SUM( a.inicio > NOW( ) AND a.situacao =2 ) AS agendados, 
       SUM( DATE_ADD( a.inicio, INTERVAL a.duracao HOUR ) <= NOW( ) AND a.situacao =2 AND a.id_vencedor = -2 ) AS analise, 
       SUM( a.prazoi > NOW( ) AND a.situacao =2 AND a.id_vencedor >0 ) AS aguardando_execucao, 
       SUM( a.situacao =0 ) AS cancelados, 
       SUM( DATE_ADD( a.inicio, INTERVAL a.duracao HOUR ) <= NOW( ) AND a.situacao =2 AND a.id_vencedor = -3 ) AS fracassados, 
       SUM( a.prazot < NOW( )  AND a.situacao =2 AND a.id_vencedor >0 AND ( b.id_avaliacao IS NULL  OR b.id_avaliacao =  '' ) ) AS avaliacao, 
       SUM( a.situacao =2 AND a.id_vencedor >0 AND a.prazot > NOW( )  AND a.prazoi <= NOW( ) ) AS execucao 
FROM leilao_pregoes a 
LEFT JOIN leilao_avaliacao b ON a.id_pregao = b.id_pregao AND b.situacao = 1
INNER JOIN leilao_edital c ON a.id_edital = c.id_edital 
WHERE c.id_comprador =1
```

I know that this can be improved...

Comment: Start by formatting it, so both you and other people can understand it.

Comment: This is going to be quite an open question, because you're doing so much in one statement, and we don't have all of the required information, e.g. data types, number of entries, etc.  But either way you're question could do with some re-formatting.

Comment: to improve query time you probably should add **indexes** where useful for that query. I believe the query itself cannot be improved (or mysql should do that for you in the worst case) but you're not doing anything majorly crazy, as far as I can tell. indexes on those attributes you use in the join conditions and in the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder whether `COUNT` would be faster where feasible.

The main improvement would be to fetch the columns as records:

```
cotacoes    123
n_publicar   456
...

SELECT 'cotacoes', SUM(...)
...
UNION SELECT 'n_publicar', SUM(...)
...
```

The reason being that the conditions are partially exclusing and joins could then be better exploited.

Also you might then tackle the slowest SELECT separately. And you could do parallel queries, splitting in subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

```
LEFT JOIN leilao_avaliacao b ON a.id_pregao = b.id_pregao AND b.situacao = 1
```

`leilao_avaliacao` needs `INDEX(id_pregao, situacao)` in either order.

```
INNER JOIN leilao_edital c ON a.id_edital = c.id_edital
WHERE c.id_comprador =1
```

`leilao_edital` needs `INDEX(id_comprador, id_edital)` in either order

For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and give us some hints of how big the tables are.